# How do I set up a user that can access other users' mailboxes in Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007, imap

I am using IMAP to connect to a exchange. I want to have one user to login with that has access to all other users' mailboxes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is allow the permissions on the Exchange Server.  Note that Admins are not given access by default like they would in NTFS.    So I usually create a user group with the user(s) I want to be able to access the mailbox(es) and add them in Exchange Management Console.
I'm usually doing this one at a time, but you could probably use PowerScript to automate it.

Comment: do they still have the explicit deny for - if i recall correctly - enterprise admins that they did in 2003?

Comment: not sure how to implement these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with IMAP. The protocol lacks any mechanism other than Login to determine which mailbox is to be accesed, nor has Exchange provided a virtual folder system where an IMAP client can pick from the full array of accounts (as represented by folders) on the system. IMAP wasn't designed for single-login access to multiple mailboxes.

This kind of thing is much better handled through Outlook Web Access, which does have mechanisms for specifying mailbox after login. This is how we handle this problem for those cases where people need to access other mailboxes.

Comment: OK. any recommendation to access mail from multiple boxes to be processed by a windows service. having a list of usernames and passwords to pop boxes is not the desired approach. admin nightmare maintaining lists of passwords.

I want to do something with ldap/active directory (get list of boxes to check) and have single user/password and some protocol to access the mail for processing.

Comment: Blackberry Enterprise Server does just this kind of thing in order to do what it does, so it is possible. It uses MAPI combined with a user with full access to the entire Exchange system. MAPI is the key here, since it's the best way to talk to multiple mailboxes. I don't know what kind of software does this, I just know it exists.